# File permission issue when uploading via Eclipse with Aptana plugin

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I have weird issue and probably it will take me ages to find answer to it in Google...

I'm using EasyEclipse for PHP and I've Aptana plugin installed on it (only for being able to ftp files directly from Eclipse).

When I create file or folder in Eclipse and upload to ftp via ecplise - file permission is set to 666.

Does anyone know what settings must be changed in order to get 664 ?

Comment: I have this issue with Aptana Studio 3, have you made any progress on this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set default file permissions in Aptana Studio 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448931/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-in-aptana-studio-3)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late - but I had the same problem and found this question with no answer.  Later I found same query with an answer that works so anyone else still searching should check here... [how to set default file permissions in Aptana Studio 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448931/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-in-aptana-studio-3)

Comment: I will try solution later and let you know how I get on

Comment: This solution is working fine, finally. Thanks GreybeardTheUnready