# how to set default file permissions in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: permissions, aptana, aptana3

Every time I upload a file to the remote host and try to open it, I get the "Internal Server Error" message and file permissions get set to "666" which needs to be "644" to open. How do I set default file permissions to be set to "644"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Open the Preferences dialog: `Window > Preferences`
2. Then go to: `Aptana Studio > Publishing > FTP` (You can just type
   'ftp' into the search box)
3. That will bring you to the settings page below where you can set the
   default permissions for new files and folders:
   [image: Aptana Studio 3 FTP Preferences]
4. Then adjust to your desired permissions for Uploads and/or Downloads
5. You can choose different default permissions for files and folders by selecting `for Files` or `for Folders` from the drop-down menu

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to switch to Netbeans because of this issue and now I will definitely use Aptana 3 for my future Django projects.

Comment: I do this and i still get the internal server error (selected all read/write/execute) … What could go wrong? :(